# How to save pair ids in many-to-many relationship in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This question is a quite tough. App has a rfq model:

```
class Rfq < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_blongs_to_many :standards
end
```

table rfqs_standards has been created with two columns only: one for rfq_id and another for standard_id.

Embeded standard selection in rfq new form. Here is how the source of html page looks like:

```
  <div class="input select optional">
    <label class="select optional" for="rfq_standard_ids"> Standard：</label>
    <select class="select optional" id="rfq_standard_ids" multiple="multiple" name="rfq[standard_ids][]" size="5">
      <option value="1">FCC15</option>
      <option value="2">Roth EU</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

As you can see from the source, the rfq[standard_ids] will carry the input value for standard.

My question is how to save the pair of rfq_id and standard_id into table rfqs_standards along with the saving of rfq?

A setter was defined in rfq model to save ids into the rfqs_standards. However the setter did was only to save the same rfq 3 times (there are 3 standard selections on rfq new page) and did nothing to save the id pair. The setter is:

```
  def standard_ids=(attributes)
    attributes.each do |attr|
      standards.build(attr)
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: Rails generates a standard_ids= method for you. Did you try without your overridden setter method?

Comment: Without the stter standard_ids=, only rfq gets saved and nothing done with the pair id. As a matter of fact, even with the setter defined, there is still no saving for the pair ids.

Comment: To whom voted -1: if you think this question is trivial, then you must know the answer to it. Why do you post your answer??? I searched online quite a few times and did not find an answer. The one which is close is railscasts.com complex form which deals with one-to-many relationship. The question here is about many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. In create of rfq controller, add:

```
  #save into join table rfqs_standards
  params[:rfq][:standard_ids].each do |sid|
    @rfq.standards << Standard.find(sid.to_i)
  end
```

This loop adds each of the standard selected to @rfq.standards. When @rfq.save, the pair id gets saved into join table rfqs_standards.